# New jQuery animation pauses active animation

Tags: jquery

I've ran into a strange issue where starting a jQuery animation within the same containing area of an already running animation causes the old animation to stop.

Please note - the problem is not multiple animations running simultaneously, the problem is running multiple animations simultaneously **within the same container tag**.

For whatever reason starting a new animation while another is already running within the same containing area will result in the previous animation stopping and the new one starting, but the old animation isn't completely stopped because it's callback function is still getting called after it "finishes", it just stops animating the second the new animation starts.

Here is the javascript used to start an animation:

```
$("#" + randid).animate({marginTop: '+=450px'}, {duration: 2000, easing: "linear", complete: function() { removeMe($("#" + randid)) }});
```

Go ahead and click the Start Animation button a few times and you'll see what I mean, circles dropping within the same  tag will break if there is more then 1 at a time.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rkogvxps/4/

Answer (score 0):

Animation HTML should be added with .append() not .html(), my hacky appending caused the animation to reset.